# Supported cultures and marketplace description

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace

Is it possible to have multiple cultures supported in a WP7 application, but with a unique language description in marketplace?
I can maybe translate some keywords, but writing a description in any languages is not easy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to write a description, in each supported language, for your application. So if you want to support multiple cultures, you should ask people on the internet to help you translate the descriptions.

You can't have a single, English, description of your application, that's used for all cultures.

The marketplace will detect what cultures you're supporting in your actual application, upon submission.